# Unique violation when I was training my conversation service

Tags: watson-conversation

In my conversation service, I'm using Watson conversation service. In dialog nodes, one branch has sub-nodes. When I train the bolt, it didn't go to the sub-node I defined, so I picked the one I defined, but I got "Unable to change the intent. Error: Unique Violation". What does this error mean? How to fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Emily

Comment: Can you share any code?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such an error when you try to add a question to an intent that is a duplicate to an all ready defined question within the same intent. It also happens when you try and define a duplicate to an Entity.
Double check your questions. Otherwise I think we will need more info or examples of the code etc.